# How EnhancedVideoRenderer works

Tags: wpf-mediakit

I've try use MediaUriElement set VideoRenderer to VideoMixingRenderer9 and works well.

I want try use MediaUriElement even set VideoRenderer to  EnhancedVideoRenderer to compare performance but I don't be able display anything with EnhancedVideoRenderer mode.

I've try this but anything:

- 1- Install, for example, K-Lite Codec Pack
- 2- Open "Lav Video" tool and change "Hardware Decoder to use" field to DXVA2
- 3- Open EvrPresenter solution and compile it
- 4- Open WPF-MediaKit solution and replace the EvrPresenter.ddl on "Test Application" project to EvrPresenter.ddl generated in the previous step
- 5- In MainWindow.xaml add VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer" in controls:MediaUriElement tag: controls:MediaUriElement x:Name="mediaUriElement" VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer" ...controls:MediaUriElement>; .... Or you can simple change the default value in VideoRendererProperty property to VideoRendererType.EnhancedVideoRenderer
- 6- Compile and start the "Test Application"

Any suggestion to use MediaUriElement with EnhancedVideoRenderer instead VideoMixingRenderer9 ?

Regards,
Rinaldo

Comment: The file is named `Test Application\EVRPresenter32.dll`, make sure you have proper 32 or 64 bit version compiled and no other `EVRPresenterXY.dll` in your `Test Application` folder.

Comment: Dear i've already proper version. But why i must recompile on my pc? I dont understand this. Bye